# StreamReader replacing a non-breaking space with a + symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

I'm taking fields from a webform and trying to save the inputs to the database. It is currently replacing a non-breaking space with a '+' symbol (ie "Test 2" = "Test+2")  As you will see below I have a hack that replaces a + from the string and replaces it with a " ".

I know this is a short-sided solution.  I would have thought the 'Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8") would have taken care of that. I'd like to find some sort of encoding that would account for any types of characters.  See the code below:

```
private List<Alias> GetAliasesFromPost()
{
    List<Alias> aliases = new List<Alias>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
    {
        string[] postedValues = sr.ReadLine().Split('&');
        for (int i = 0; i < postedValues.Length; i++)
        {
            if (postedValues[i].StartsWith("urlAlias="))
            {
                Alias alias = new Alias();
                string active = postedValues[i - 1].Replace("active=", string.Empty);
                alias.Active = string.Compare(active, "on", true) == 0;
                alias.UrlAlias = postedValues[i].Replace("urlAlias=", string.Empty);
                alias.Notes = postedValues[i + 1].Replace("notes=", string.Empty).Replace("+", " ");
                int Id = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(postedValues[i + 2].Replace("id=", string.Empty), out Id);
                alias.Id = Id;
                aliases.Add(alias);
            }
        }
    }
    return aliases;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the specific problem you are asking, use UrlDecode in your `postedValues` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx

But you should really not parse the `Request`. Just use `Request.Params`, the values will be already parsed and decoded there.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to StreamReaders, I have added new using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Params); It doesn't seem to like the overload.